# jQuery hide() does not work on safari

Tags: jquery, html, safari, zurb-foundation

I have a very specific problem with mobile safari. When I use .show() or .hide() for my menu in Chrome it works. But on Safari it does show, but won't hide the menu. Display: block just keeps existing. Don't know how to fix and everything I find won't help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Foundation for Sites</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"><script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
        // jQuery Mobile's Ajax navigation does not work in all cases (e.g.,
        // when navigating from a mobile to a non-mobile page), especially when going back, hence disabling it.
        $.extend($.mobile, {
            ajaxEnabled: false
        });
    });
</script>

<script src="js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

```
$(document).foundation();


$('#menu').click(function(){
  $('#side-menu').show( "slide", 700 );
  $('#overlay').show( "fade", 700 );
});

$('#close').click(function(){
  $('#side-menu').hide( "slide", 700 );
  $('#overlay').hide( "fade", 700 );
});

$('.overlay').click(function(){
  $('#side-menu').hide( "slide", 700 );
  $('#overlay').hide( "fade", 700 );
});

$('#side-menu > a').click(function(){
  $('#side-menu').hide( "slide", 700 );
  $('#overlay').hide( "fade", 700 );
});

$('#side-menu > li').click(function(){
  $('#side-menu').hide( "slide", 700 );
  $('#overlay').hide( "fade", 700 );
});
```

Comment: I having a doubt , that it might to be jquery issue , but maybe css issue that your element maybe overlaping the other elements on safari.

Comment: Fixed it by removing the hide animation from jQuery UI. Without the animation it goes to the anchor tag and removes the menu. Don't know why. It looks like that the animation crashed or something.